# insert text so i can .print()

Tags: jquery, printing, replacewith

I have a field called `exp delivery date` so i need the user to put a date in and then press **print**. However the print function doesn't catch the inputted text. So i did this:

```
$('#exp').live('change',function(){         
                var deliv = $('#exp').val();
                $('#delivDate').replaceWith("<p id='delivDate'>" + deliv + "</p>");
                $('#exp').val('');
            });
```

'#exp' is the input id and '#delivDate' is a `<p>` tag right next to the input. I'm only doing this so the `.print()` will catch it?

Can anyone think of a better way to do this? (it doesn't work in IE but does in FF by the way)

Comment: What doesn't work in IE? The replacement or the print?

Comment: Sadly, I think the best cross-browser way of doing this is to have your form submission produce a new, print-friendly version of the page with the form values filled in, and then print that.

Comment: its annoying because its the only field on the page that needs input!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to accomplish this might be to use a jQuery plugin called **[Print Element](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/printElement)** which is able to print any specific element existing in the DOM. Or all of it.

---

If have trouble figuring out the mechanics on how to make the inputted text printable then here's a sample:

```
<textarea id="exp"></textarea>
<p id="delivDate"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#exp').live('change',function(){          
    var deliv = $('#exp').val();
    $('#exp').css('display', 'none'); // optional
    $('#delivDate').text(deliv);
    $('#exp').val(''); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah but from what I understand he can print but he just can't print the value in the textbox, that's why he's replacing it with a `<p>` tag.